# Table style customization

Tags: tables, colortbl

How to remove the extra color on the left and right of the rows?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}
{\rowcolors{2}{gray!40}{gray!20}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\bigskip
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular} [H]{@{} l l l@{}}
    \toprule
    xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    \midrule
    111 & 222 & 333 \\
    444&555&666\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: remove `@{}` in table columns specification!

Comment: But I don't want extra space.

Comment: you define "extras space",  so i dont' understant what you like to obtain. if you like to have only "extra" space between column, you need to redefine table layout. can you define its width in advance?

Comment: What I want is to get rid of the extra color (out of the lines border) and to fill the first and last row (not the head) to fill the white area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

To get rid of the white space around the `rule`s, you have to reset the value of both `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` to zero. The default values are `\belowrulesep=.65ex` and `\aboverulesep=.4ex` for booktabs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}   
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\bigskip
\label{tab:1}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!40}{gray!20} 
\begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{-1\tabcolsep}}l l l<{\hspace{-1\tabcolsep}}} 
    \toprule  
    xxx & xxx & xxx \\ \midrule
    111 & 222 & 333 \\
    444 & 555 & 666 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, How to fill the white area in the first and last row?

Comment: Well, I edited my answer to remove that white space